# Software to convert your PC into mBass provider

Tags: android, backend, saas

I am working on developing an android app and have searched a lot online for free mBass provider. But its very limited there(with tight limits). I do not want to get billed for extra use at this stage. I just thought that if there is possibility if I can convert my PC into mBass provider. I am looking for some software that I can install on my local machine and make it a bass provider. Please help me if this is possible.
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly you need from mbass?

Comment: mobile backend as a service.Sorry for confusion.Also there is not tag on stackoverflow for that and i can not create that having lesser reputation points :(

Comment: I've asked what 'exactly' you need from it. I know what doesn't it mean.

Comment: I want to convert my PC into mBass provider so that I can test my app using my own resources.

Comment: Everything that mbass providers like parse, backendless offer right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77958/discussion-between-amit-yo-and-divers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution for this which is open source BAASBOX.
http://www.baasbox.com/android-sdk-overview/
I will give it a try and update my answer.